# Beginner SQL database manipulation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am brand spankin new to SQL, I was trying to complete this little objective, however I keep getting... Empty set (0.00 sec)

### Task:

1) List all the items with their extended price (quantity * price)

2) List the total cost of all the items in the store

### My input:

```
mysql> select * from store where price = Qty*Price;
```

what I believe I have said is... select ALL from "store" where my new updated price is now equal to the Qty*Price..

### Which gets me...

Empty set (0.00 sec)

### Heres my code for "store".

```
INSERT INTO `store` (`Id`, `Name`, `Qty`, `Price`) VALUES

    (1, 'apple', 10, 1),

    (2, 'pear', 5, 2),

    (3, 'banana', 10, 1.5),

    (6, 'lemon', 100, 0.1),

    (5, 'orange', 50, 0.2);
```

Can anyone help as to why this is happening??

Thank you!

Comment: Your select statement is: 
Select all the columns (Id, Name, Qty, Price) and look at each row, and check where the column Price is equal to Qty * price.
E.g. for (1, 'apple', 10, 1), Price = 1, and Qty = 10, so check if 1 = 10* 1 (which is false). Try putting what you have in the where clause, in the select statment.

Comment: Ahh that makes more sense, Thank you Vincent!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using....

### SELECT *,  Qty * Price as 'Total Price' From store;

Which combined a few peoples responses and got the answer/format I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

1) List all the items with their extended price (quantity * price):

```
SELECT Qty*Price as extended_price FROM store
```

2) List the total cost of all the items in the store:

```
SELECT SUM(Qty*Price) as total_cost FROM store
```

Comment: Thank you @rbr94 this makes plenty of sense!

Comment: yes it did!! I ended up using SELECT *,  Qty * Price as 'Total Price' From store; Which utilized what you were saying and printed out my full table. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [MySQL docs for the WHERE clause](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php) say:

> The MySQL WHERE clause is used to filter the results from a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.

so you are trying to filter out all the rows where the value of a column named `price` equals the values of the columns `QTY * PRICE` which *never occurs* in your `store` table ... hence the empty set of results.

You should update your queries as shown in @rbr94's response

Comment: Thank you for your comment!